# PyQt5 GUI Freezing even with MultiThreading

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to write a PyQt5 program with start and stop buttons. For both the start and stop buttons, I am using two different functions that connect to the Twitter API. When I click on the start button, the GUI freezes and my cursor is constantly "processing" and does not let me click on the stop button. I tried multi-threading and this still occurs.
This is my program:

```
class TwitterMain(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        loadUi('twittermain.ui', self)

        self.thread = {}
        self.startcollect.clicked.connect(self.start_worker_1)
        self.startanalyze.clicked.connect(self.start_worker_2)
        self.stopcollect.clicked.connect(self.stop_worker_1)
        self.stopanalyze.clicked.connect(self.stop_worker_2)

    def start_worker_1(self):
        self.thread[1] = ThreadClass(parent=None, index=1)
        self.thread[1].start()
        self.thread[1].any_signal.connect(self.datacollection)
        self.startcollect.setEnabled(False)

    def start_worker_2(self):
        self.thread[2] = ThreadClass(parent=None, index=2)
        self.thread[2].start()
        self.thread[2].any_signal.connect(self.datacollection)
        self.startanalyze.setEnabled(False)

    def stop_worker_1(self):
        self.thread[1].stop()
        self.stopcollect.setEnabled(True)

    def stop_worker_2(self):
        self.thread[2].stop()
        self.stopanalyze.setEnabled(True)

    def datacollection(self, counter):
        #data collection from twitter API using tweepy

class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    any_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None, index=0):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.index = index
        self.is_running = True

    def run(self):
        print('Starting thread...', self.index)
        cnt = 0
        while (True):
            cnt += 1
            if cnt == 99: cnt = 0
            time.sleep(0.01)
            self.any_signal.emit(cnt)

    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False
        print('Stopping thread...', self.index)
        self.terminate()
```

I'm not entirely sure why it isn't working. There is more code above and below it connecting it to the GUI but this is the main page. I'm only trying to make the start1 and stop1 work and will replicate it for the second set of start and stop. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `terminate()`? The documentation [clearly says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate) that it's a dangerous function, its usage is discouraged and it should be used only if absolutely necessary. It's also not thread-safe, and you're calling it from the main thread, which means that, depending on the OS, it could also be potentially blocking. You're already setting the `is_running` flag, there shouldn't be any need for anything else.

Comment: Do `while self.is_running:` and get rid of `self.terminate()`. Also, the signals should be connected *before* calling `start()`.